# horizontal scroll with height fixed on 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css

here is what I created http://jsfiddle.net/ZygnV/

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.main-content-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.main-sidebar {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 220px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.main-content {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content-wrapper">
  <nav class="main-sidebar">
  </nav>
  <section id="main-content" class="main-content">

  </section>
</div>
```

the problem is that little vertical scroll: I would like to not have it.

Why this little bug? And how can I fix it? I thought to set overflow-y:hidden but I don't think it's the best solution: if I would set a min-height and then display the scroll it would be always hidden (unless I act with a js script)

Comment: Give overflow-y:hidden; in CSS for body

Comment: Why the `.main-content` has `width: 10000px`? This is the property which causes the problem. Do you need it for any specific reason?

Comment: @matewka see my reply to Sowmya

Answer (score 3):

There shouldn't be vertical scroll in the first place.

The reason behind it is that both `nav` and `section`are `display: inline-block`, so spaces in code formatting affect layout. There are [various ways to solve the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements), one of them would be to set `font-size: 0` on `.main-content-wrapper` and desired `font-size` on children.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZygnV/2/).

Alternatively, you can use different approach to place sidebar and content, [flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) perform extremely good in this scenario.

Comment: great. I used `display: inline-block` for `nav` and `section` to achieve my objective: a horizontal layout. But I never thought to set `font-size` property to their container. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 1):

This could help you

```
    .main-content {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10000px;
   }
   .main-sidebar {
    background-color: #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 220px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:hidden` to main div

```
.main-content-wrapper{
            height: 100%;
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow:hidden
        }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/IFITOXIh/2/)**

Comment: excuse me, maybe I was not enough clear, in fact I forgot to say that I would like to have the horizontal scroll (that's the reason why the main-content has 10000px of width (just to show the horizontal scroll). Then, as I have already said, I could set overflow-y:hidden but then how to show the vertical scrollbar when a certain min-height is reached? I should act with js, ok, but is there a simpler way(only css, not javascript)?